# list all combinations of what a user can select based on a list of items from a c# listbox

Tags: algorithm, permutation, combinations

I have a listbox in C# with the following items:

```
Package1
Package2
Package3
Package4
Package5
and so on...
```

The user can select multiple items from this listbox. I need an algorithm in c# or Java (preferably in c#) that can tell me all the possible selections that a user can do, for example Package1 and Package2, Package3 and Package1, Package2, Package4 and Package 3, etc.

Comment: show us what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion, "guess" if the first package is in the combination or not - and invoke recursively without the first package.

Pseudo-code:

```
combinations(packages, sol):
   if (packages.length == 0): //base clause
      print sol
      return
   package <- packages.first //1 possibility: the first package is in the combination
   packages.removeFirst()
   sol.append(package) 
   combinations(packages,sol) //recursively invoke without the first package
   sol.removeLast() //clean up environment - remove the last added package
   combinations(packages,sol) //2nd possibility: the first package is not in the combination
```

**Notes:**

- The empty solution [no package was selected] is assumed to be also a feasible option in this algorithm - if it is not, it can be handled easily in the base clause.
- It is assumed that the order is not important. Package1 AND Package2 is the same as Package2 AND Package1.
- There are `2^n` possible combinations for chosing packages, so any algorithm that do what you ask for [including this one] will need `O(2^n)` time, so I would not try to invoke this algorithm with 100 packages....

In java, it could look something like this:

```
public static void printCombinations(LinkedList<String> packages, LinkedList<String> sol) {
    if (packages.size() == 0) { 
        System.out.println(sol);
        return;
    }
    String pack = packages.poll(); //also removes the head
    sol.addLast(pack);
    printCombinations(new LinkedList(packages),sol);
    sol.removeLast();
    printCombinations(new LinkedList(packages),sol);
}
```

and invokation is by:

```
printCombinations(packages, new LinkedList<String>());
```

Where `packages` is a `LinkedList` with all your packages.

- I used `LinkedList` for `packages` and created new objects because I
  find it more clear. To enhance performance - you can use a single
  array with `index` [which will be changed between recursive calls] in
  order to avoid duplicating `packages` so many times.

Comment: Thx.Now I have:public static void main(String[] args)
{
LinkedList<String> packages = new LinkedList<String>();
packages.addAll((Arrays.asList(args)));
printCombinations(packages, new LinkedList<String>());
}
public static void printCombinations( LinkedList<String> packages, LinkedList<String> sol) {
if (packages.size() == 0) { 
System.out.println(sol);
return;
}
String pack = packages.poll(); //also removes the head
sol.addLast(pack);
printCombinations(new LinkedList(packages),sol);
sol.removeLast();printCombinations(new LinkedList(packages),sol);
}//HowDoIDisplayTheOutputOfThisandTheReverse

Comment: @RalphZayas: This is unreadable and I cannot understand what you are asking.

Comment: The function that you wrote works great and it displays this:

Comment: [Package1, Package2, Package3, Package4]
[Package1, Package2, Package3]
[Package1, Package2, Package4]
[Package1, Package2]
[Package1, Package3, Package4]
[Package1, Package3]
[Package1, Package4]
[Package1]
[Package2, Package3, Package4]
[Package2, Package3]
[Package2, Package4]
[Package2]
[Package3, Package4]
[Package3]
[Package4]                                                          Now I justneedtodisplay the opposite of every result combination from above. For example for [Package3, Package4] then I will display [Package4, Package3] (that one is easy) what If I have 3 items on the set?

Comment: @RalphZayas: You can use [`Collections.reverse(sol)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29)